# Nautilus can't extract password protected 7zip files

Tags: nautilus, 7zip

Upon right clicking the 7z-file and selecting "Extract Here", the cursor changes to a progress animation. Nothing else happens, but the system becomes somewhat slow. Nautilus and gnome-shell processes will use a lot of CPU until I close Nautilus.

Here's what DOES work however:

- Extracting password protected 7z-files in the terminal.
- Extracting 7z-files without passwords in Nautilus.
- Extracting password protected rar-files in Nautilus.

Ubuntu version 17.10.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known issue](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/merge_requests/72) that has been already fixed and merged in [nautilus master](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/tree/master) on Feb 13, 2018:

> If archive decompression fails due to missing support, Nautilus tries
>   to launch the default application for the file type, which results in
>   an infinite loop in cases where Nautilus is the default application.
>   This commit removes that code and makes an application chooser always
>   appear with a heading to inform the user.

While this fix does prevent Nautilus from crashing/using all CPU, it will not add 7z support in Nautilus.